# How can I read a copy of the data arriving at the master end of a PTY?

Tags: python, linux, file-io, posix

I have the file descriptor of the master end of a pty. This pty is used by a library (libvte) to spawn and run subprocesses.

- I can poll and read from the file descriptor or duplicate of it, but then data never gets to the library.
- I can poll and read from the file descriptor, then write it back to the master, but then I get into a nasty loop reading back my own data, and again nothing gets through to the underlying library.

Is there any solution to allow me to read a copy of the data without interfering with the underlying functionality at the pty?

I am using Python, but I don't think it really matters at this level.

Comment: Do you have some code you can share?

Comment: import vte; t = vte.Terminal(); fd = t.get_pty(); # now read from fd

Answer (score 1):

Check out my [pypty](http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/pypty/) program - it's a Python reimplementation of /usr/bin/script with a bit of extra functionality, so it demonstrates both ends of PTY communication in Python:

BTW, beware of signals with (relatively) naked system calls - they may return when only partially complete.  See in particular the maybe_restarted_syscall function.  And just resizing a window will tend to cause signals to be delivered when using a PTY.

Comment: Thanks that is pretty cool, but I am not sure it answers my question, I only have a single FD to read and write from, where you read from stdin, and write to stdout (while also writing to another file). Since you are much more expert than me, I hope I am wrong, but please explain.